# Always get CORS rejection when trying to connect to AWS WebSockets API Gateway

Tags: websocket, socket.io, cors, aws-api-gateway

I can connect to my WebSocket API Gateway with wscat. And can confirm I'm seeing log messages at the http endpoint the $connect route points to.

But if I try any other type of application (I tried from a local html/vue.js project, from a hosted website with a domain, I tried from a chrome browser extension) using socket.io, I get the following CORS rejection:

```
access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://****.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoRmmeX' from origin '****' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

VM26:1 GET https://****.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoRmmeX net::ERR_FAILED
```

The HTTP endpoints are not called and no logs are submitted when it fails like this.

My WebSocket API Gateway has been set up with no authorizers. Only the default $connect and $disconnect route. Each pointing to an external HTTP endpoint (which basically just logs right now). It's as is when first created other than that.

Help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is AJAX not WebSockets.

Comment: have you enables cors for aws-api-gateway api ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this problem?